# Sort List of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, collections

I have a collection of dictionary values (a `List<>`) that I need to sort. Basically each dictionary is a 'row' and the collection is a page of rows. A simple example;

```
       var data = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
       data.Add(new Dictionary<string,string>() {
                    { "Firstname", "Bob"},
                    { "Lastname", "Banana"}
       });
       data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    { "Firstname", "Amy"},
                    { "Lastname", "Apple"}
       });
       data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    { "Firstname", "Charlie"},
                    { "Lastname", "Coconut"}
       });
       data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    { "Firstname", "Andy"},
                    { "Lastname", "Apple"}
       });
```

The sort string generated is "SQL" like, example

```
 Lastname asc, Firstname desc
```

I have tried `.OrderBy()` on the data object but that doesn't seem to work right against the KeyValuePairs.

Any idea how I could get the data list to be sorted to be in this order, using the dynamic sort statement:

```
 Apple, Andy
 Apple, Amy
 Banana, Bob
 Coconut, Charlie
```

Using .NET 4.0 if some fancy LINQ will work. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Curious as to why you are using a dictionary for each 'row'?

Comment: As a side-note, when you want to store "properties" of "objects" like this, you should create a class, not use dictionaries.

Comment: The 'columns' are dynamic by user. So each user can have various 'columns' selected or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  private static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> Sort(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> data, string orderByString)
  {
     var orderBy =
        orderByString.Split(',').Select(
           s => s.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .Select (a => new {Field=a[0],Descending = "desc".Equals (a[1], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)})
           .ToList ();
     if (orderBy.Count == 0)
        return data;
     // First one is OrderBy or OrderByDescending.
     IOrderedEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> ordered =
        orderBy[0].Descending ? data.OrderByDescending (d => d[orderBy[0].Field]) : data.OrderBy (d => d[orderBy[0].Field]);
     for (int i = 1; i < orderBy.Count; i++)
     {
        // Rest are ThenBy or ThenByDescending.
        var orderClause = orderBy[i];
        ordered =
           orderBy[i].Descending ? ordered.ThenByDescending(d => d[orderClause.Field]) : ordered.ThenBy(d => d[orderClause.Field]);
     }
     return ordered;
  }
```

Comment: a bit more dynamic already. Good point about case insensitive comparison - I'll nick that from you :)

Comment: Great solution, though I am just trying to figure out a way to remove the hard coded index values

Comment: OK instead of plain string defining the sort columns, direction and order, I am using typed data entity, List<SortInfo>, which contains ColumnName and IsAscending columns, so I need not work individual indexes

Answer (score 5):

```
data.OrderBy(dict => dict["Lastname"])
    .ThenByDescending(dict => dict["Firstname"])
```

If it's dynamic:

```
var sorted = data.OrderBy(item => 1); // identity (stable) sort
orderby = "Lastname asc, Firstname desc";
foreach (var key in orderby.Split(',').Select(clause => clause.Trim()))
{
    if (key.EndsWith(" desc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        key = key.Substr(0, key.Length - 5);
        sorted = data.ThenByDescending(dict => dict[key]);
    } else
    {
        if (key.EndsWith(" asc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            key = key.Substr(0, key.Length - 4);
        }
        sorted = data.ThenBy(dict => dict[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added some sample code (without error checking!) that allows a dynamic orderby specification with (optional) `asc` or `desc` modifiers. _No compiler ever saw this code, so it may contain silly typo's_

Comment: +1 for beating me to the answer... I started out a little more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you have the best implementation here, but as the above is an example and not a real world case, here you go:

```
data
.OrderBy(x => x["Lastname"])
.ThenByDescending(x => x["Firstname"])
.Select(x => 
    new 
    { 
        Lastname = x["Lastname"],
        Firstname = x["Firstname"],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific reason you need to use Dictionaries, for which I can't think, something similiar to this would be better;

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName  {get; set;}
}

var people = new [] {
    new Person { FirstName = "Amy", LastName = "Apple" },
    new Person { FirstName = "Andy", LastName = "Apple" },
    new Person { FirstName = "Charlie", LastName = "Coconut" } 
};

var sortedPeople = people
    .OrderBy(f => f.LastName)
    .ThenByDescending(f => f.FirstName);
```

**Updated based on comments;**

See this post for a possible solution;

[Entity Framework 4.1 simple dynamic expression for object.property = value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499995/entity-framework-4-1-simple-dynamic-expression-for-object-property-value/6500016)

and

[Dynamic linq query with multiple/unknown criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453420/dynamic-linq-query-with-multiple-unknown-criteria)

(the above has now been fully implemented as below)

```
public static int UpdateSegment(int segmentId)
{
    Table<ContactViewItem> Contacts;
    var  conditionsFormatted = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //Retrieve all conditions
    var segmentConditions = Lists.GetSegmentConditions(segmentId);

    //Iterate through conditions and process them
    foreach (var condition in segmentConditions)
    {
        switch (condition.Operator)
        {
            case SegmentCondition.OperatorType.Equals:
                condition.Condition =  string.Format("{1}=\"{0}\"", condition.Criteria, condition.Field);
                break;
            case SegmentCondition.OperatorType.Contains:
                condition.Condition = string.Format("{1}.Contains(\"{0}\")", condition.Criteria, condition.Field);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected Operator for Condition");
        }
    }


    var db = new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["c"].ConnectionString);

    var statusConditions = "Status = 1";

    var results = (IQueryable)db.Contacts.Where(statusConditions);

    var distinctFields = (from c in segmentConditions select c.Field).Distinct();

    foreach (var distinctField in distinctFields)
    {
        var values = (from s in segmentConditions where s.Field == distinctField select s.Condition).ToArray();
        var valuesJoined = string.Join("||", values);
        results = results.Where(valuesJoined);
    }

    results = results.Select("id");


    var xml = new StringBuilder();
    xml.Append("<Ids>");

    foreach (var id in results)
    {
        xml.Append(String.Format("<Id>{0}</Id>", id));
    }
    xml.Append("</Ids>");

    var idXml = XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString());

    return Lists.UpdateSegmentContacts(idXml.ToString(), segmentId);

}
```

Might help, then again, might not!

Comment: nice addition, but still not dynamic; If you use non-anonymous types like this, DLINQ might apply

Comment: woah... entity framework, database connection strings, tables, linq to XML, system overload! This gotta be something very complex; but I can't see the forest anymore :) Then again, perhaps the OP is getting it's data from a similar source and it might not be be all that... erm... convoluted as it might seem at first glance?

Comment: PS. Prefer .AsQueryable() extension to the `(IQueryable)` cast; the extension allows better expression derivation and more compile time checks

Comment: indeed, but it solved a specific problem very well. Will refactor what I can when I get onto the technical debt backlog. Tests go green for now!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just paste the wrong snippet? I don't see where the xml comes in, nor what the function `UpdateSegment` is supposed to be called like/with...

Comment: It's a bit of a hack. Basically, all I was interested in was the IDs that met the conditions, these are completely dynamic with any number of fields/conditions/operators. To XML conversion is because I didnt want to use EF to bulk insert what could be 100k+ records and generating the XML, which is sent to an Sproc, was the easiest option at the time. As said, needs to be cleaned up when I have more time, but as far as the conditional querying goes, is spot on.

Comment: @Chris: ok, I see where you are going with this; I will +1 this when you show us how to use this for the OP's question;  <tongue-in-cheek>Kind of brings a whole new meaning to the term _eXtreme Programming_ does it? I could be skeptic here and say you have a green bar because you don't have enough tests -- but really I shouldn't because I can't see all the code (what is `ContactsViewItem`, `Lists.GetSegmentConditions(segmentId)`, etc)</tongue-in-cheek>