# How to search through all fields of a table in Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

This is a ASP.NET MVC project.
I want to query a database table with a specific value of a textbox from the view.
This queries two fields:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    return View(db.KDtable
                  .Where(x =>
                    x.Name.StartsWith(search)
                    || x.Description.StartsWith(search)
                    || search == null)
                  .ToList()
                );
}
```

`string search` is the value of the textbox.

**Question:**

How can I, instead of adding all fields manually to the lambda expression e.g. `x.City.StartsWith(search)`, just plain and simple query all the table fields with the input from the textbox.

Thx

Comment: you want dynamic linq. have a look here http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Alongside Dynamic Linq, you might want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453420/dynamic-linq-query-with-multiple-unknown-criteria

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> CreateTextSearch<T>(string searchText)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    var props = t.GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    var searchTextExpr = Expression.Constant(searchText);
    var tParameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    Expression expr = null;
    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        var criteria = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Property(tParameterExpr, prop),
            typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
            searchTextExpr);
        if(expr == null)
            expr = criteria;
        else
            expr = Expression.Or(expr, criteria);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(expr, tParameterExpr);
}
```

call it like this: `MySet.Where(CreateTextSearch<MyType>("DDD"));` for IQueryables and `MySet.Where(CreateTextSearch<MyType>("DDD").Compile());` for regular IEnumerables.