# Using a method of a local property in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm hoping that someone will be able to tell me if a) what I'm trying to achieve is possible, and b) how to go about it.

I have a private property defined in a class of a type that is effectively a list of strings, and the class has methods defined on it that allow a bespoke search of the list. Can I use these in a lambda expression?

For example, if I have the class

```
public class SomeExampleClass : ISomeExampleClass
{

    private readonly IAlistOfBespokeStringsObject _aListOfBespokeStringsObject
```

And the type of the `AListOfBespokeStringsObject` property is defined as (it effectively takes a list of values from a database and populates it):

```
public class AListOfBespokeStringsObject : IAlistOfBespokeStringsObject
{
    private List<string> _listOfBespokeStrings;

    public AListOfBespokeStringsObject()
    {
        var db = new ListOfBespokeStringsContext();
        _listOfBespokeStrings = db.BespokeString.Select(a => a.String.Replace(" ",string.Empty)).ToList<string>();
    }

    public Boolean CheckBespokeStringList(string stringToBeChecked)
    {
        return _listOfBespokeStrings.Any(a => a.Equals(stringToBeChecked.Replace(" ","")));
    }
}
```

Going back to the SomeExampleClass, I'm using it as a sort of rules engine, where rules are enumerated through, and the text of the rule (as a string) is passed to a lambda expression, as follows(note that dataset is just the type that the collection datasets is made up of):

```
foreach (var Rule in _rules)
{  
    var dataSets = mydatasets.AsQueryable();                            
    var exp = Rule.QueryText;

    var typ = Expression.Parameter(typeof(dataset), "p");
    var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] {typ}, null, exp);
    dataSets.Where((Expression<Func<dataset, bool>>) e).ToList().ForEach(b =>
    {
        *some course of action*
    });  
}
```

Most of the rules are fairly simple 'p.type == \"3\" ' or such like.  However, one of them needs to be more like this:

```
_listOfBespokeStringsObject.CheckBespokeStringList(p.StringToBeChecked) == true
```

where it invokes the CheckBespokeStringList method of the local property to find a match on my list of database derived strings, albeit with all spaces removed.

I'm fairly new to .net, so I'm still not fully aware of the constraints on it!

Comment: So what's the problem exactly ? what is the error you're facing ?

Comment: Can you provide a working sample (with the errors) using this:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: It's telling me: System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: Unknown identifier _listOfBespokeStringsObject'

Comment: I'll give it a go on dotnetfiddle, but it may take me some time to put it together!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453617/172729 this answer may put you on the track, the idea is to let `DynamicExpression` to know the type `AListOfBespokeStringsObject`, because it only knows about .net types.

Comment: For security reasons, from the documentation: `The accessible types are the only types that can be explicitly referenced in expressions, and method invocations in the expression language are restricted to methods declared in the accessible types.`.

Comment: Apparently `System.Linq.Dynamic` removed the test for accessible types and some version put it back - what exact version are you using? `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` has support for adding your own types to accessible types if you can switch to that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let your expression get to know the types you're using, try to define `_aListOfBespokeStringsObject` in your expression, and maybe make it public.